# how to close the application on button click in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, cordova

i am developing jquery mobile app for IOS and Android, I wanted to close the Entire Application on button click using below function still but it's not closing the APP

```
            if (navigator.app) {
                        navigator.app.exitApp();
                    }
                    else if (navigator.device) {
                        navigator.device.exitApp();

                    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `navigator.app.exitApp()` - I believe that's supported on Android. create on click function and call it on that button event

```
function ExitApp()
{
navigator.app.exitApp();
}
```

On iOS, Apple does not allow apps to programmatically exit.

but for ios you can try, in the application's plist put

```
 UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend = TRUE
```

and when the user hits the home button, the application will quit. No need for a button, no need for exit().

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW23

Comment: are you getting any error in console log .? is deviceready function firing . can you provide your code.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'mobile' of undefined at http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js (line: 2)
Uncaught module cordova/urlutil not found at cordova.js (line: 259)

Comment: Getting below exception in consloe                                  deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds. at cordova.js (line: 1773)
Channel not fired: onCordovaReady at cordova.js (line: 1766)
Channel not fired: onCordovaInfoReady at cordova.js (line: 1766)

Comment: try using the latest js. and cordova is not firing means you have not included js files properly. `navigator.app.exitApp()` is feature of cordova so you need ondevice ready to fire then you can use that feature. your problem is small just check your script tags import. jquery - jquery mobile- in the end cordova. ( hope cordova is in root folder i.e www)

Comment: I am Using ICENIUM(IDE) to develop and when we create the project in ICENIUM it will take the latest cardova below is the files included in my index file  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
     
        <script src="cordova.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery-mobile/js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: import cordova in the end after JQM and Jquery and display alert() on deviceready of cordova and check is it working properly or not.!